# matlab to C++/openCV normalization function

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, optimization

here is my matlab code:

```
imageData = imageData ./ toolbox.c3d.p.tprctile(imageData(xy),99.2);
imageData(imageData>1) = 1;
```

here is my openCV/c++ code, the matrix dst is an openCV matrix 

cv::Mat dst

```
std::vector<float> result;
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = index.begin() ; it != index.end(); ++it)
{
    int ind = *it;
    float temp = dst.at<float>(ind - 1);    
    result.push_back(temp);
}
float divider = tprctile(result,99.2);

dst = dst/ divider;
```

utility function for percentile

```
float Utils::tprctile(std::vector<float> channel, double pt)
{       
    std::sort(channel.begin(),channel.end());   
    int ptInd = Utilities::MatlabRound (pt/100 * channel.size() );
    return channel[ptInd];

    // Matlab code
    // function val = tprctile(data, pt)
    //   data = sort(data);
    //   ptInd = round( pt/100 * length(data) );
    //   val = data(ptInd);
}
```

my question is regarding `imageData(imageData>1) = 1`
what is the most efficient way to implement this function - i can of course iterate through dst like I did. is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to truncate the image with cv::threshold.

The following should do what you require:

```
cv::threshold(dst, dst, 1, 1, CV_THRESH_TRUNC);
```

This truncates all values above 1 and stores the result in dst.

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold

Answer (score 0):

this is what i'm doing at the moment

```
 int matrixSize = dst.rows *dst.cols;
    cv::MatConstIterator_<float> it = dst.begin<float>(), it_end = dst.end<float>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < matrixSize ; ++i, ++it)
    {
       float value = *it;
       if(value > 1.0)
       {
          dst.at<float>(i) = 1.0;
       }
    }
```